# How can I repair boot failure due to moved boot sector?

Tags: boot, partitioning

I just installed a home partition according to this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving). I have now deleted the old_home (backup folder) and shrunk the system partition further.
I now ask GParted (Live CD) to expand my home partition [sda3](https://imgur.com/a/2SG2I). But it gives me a [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RlGb.jpg) that the boot sector will then be moved and the system will not boot.
So, before I expand my home partition, how would I fix this error that GParted predicted will occur?

I have used the [boot repair disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) before with good result.

The system partition is located before the home partition and the boot flag is on the system partition (see [screen shot](https://imgur.com/a/2SG2I)), but I believe GParted tells me the boot sector is on the home partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move the head end of the boot partition (which is the root partition, if the /boot directory is there), you must repair grub. You can do it according to the description in this link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)

Manual methods are described as well as the automatic method with [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). You have better control, when you use the manual methods with the command line tool `grub-install`.

Comment: Thanks for all help you and others give here. Do you think GParted is extra careful giving a warning here. I am not moving the boot partition. (I can't mix things up that bad I hope.) I will probably have no boot problems?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Which partition do you intend to move? Is /boot in that partition?

Comment: If you want detailed help, you can edit the original question and post the output of the following command lines (when booted from a live drive). Indent each line four spaces to render the text as 'code'. `df`;`sudo parted -ls`;`sudo lsblk -f`;`sudo lsblk -m`

Comment: I saw your edited question and the link to the screenshot from gparted. I think that `/boot` is in `/dev/sda1` which is the root partition. You can move `/dev/sda3` which is the `/home` partition without risk for grub, but there might be other risks. All operations on the partition table are potentially risky, so keep your backups of important files.

Comment: Thank you. I try that now that I am in the Live CD. If it breaks and Boot Repair CD will not fix it, I come back with the listings.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :-)

Comment: It booted fine after expanding the home partition, so now the new home partition is like I want it. Thanks a lot to you and the other guys helping out here.