# How can I repair my legacy boot of Xubuntu 16.04 (RESOLVED)

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, uefi

Some time ago, I installed Xubuntu 16.04 on a SONY VAIO SVE1512E6EW that had a pre-installed Windows 8. As I didn't succeed in having both in UEFI mode (no grub screen and allways started in Windows 8), I installed thus Xubuntu in Legacy mode and it worked fine several weeks until yesterday, when I tried to use boot-repair!

Now Xubuntu doesn't work neither in Legacy nor UEFI modes. In Legacy mode I get a message:

```
error:file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found
grub rescue>
```

and That's it !

How could I repair my Legacy boot ? (Boot-repair refuses to work in LEGACY mode)

Here is my Boot-info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26157738/

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: The following links might help you repair grub, https://askubuntu.com/questions/966236/how-can-i-repair-boot-failure-due-to-moved-boot-sector/966238#966238 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2

Comment: Thanks for the links. I tried some methods but without success... and I am afraid to make a mess because when I type "set" after grub recue>, I get "prefix=(hd0,gpt9)/boot/grub and when I type "ls  /boot/grub" I get " error : file '/boot/grub' not found !
Would you be so kind to have a look to my Boot-info to check where is the problem : I am totally lost and don't understand how to reinstall correctly my grub  ?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to use Boot Repair in UEFI mode according to the advice at the end of the boot-info link, 'Suggested repair' and 'Final advice ...'. That way you might get the computer boot both into Windows and Xubuntu (without changing between UEFI and BIOS/legacy mode). If still no luck, I suggest that you boot Xubuntu 'live' in BIOS mode from a USB pendrive and in that system use the chroot method described  at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot ; it is somewhat complicated, but is maybe more likely to work than the other methods.

Comment: Besides other methods, I tried Boot Repair in UEFI  but at the end of the correction process, it says "no internet connection detected" which is not true because the symbol of connection is OK and the browser works fine on internet  !  I don't understand !
I'll try your other method if nobody can explain me how to use successfully Boot-repair in UEFI.

Comment: Finally I got Boot-repair to work for me : the trick was NOT to click on the automatic repair, go to the advanced options and change the grub location from sda8 to sda9. Now Windows8 and Xubuntu can be launched in UEFI !

Comment: That's great! Congratulations, and thanks for sharing your solution :-)